# Error-I can't open a new Qt project in VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2015

I've installed Qt 5.12.6 and VS2019, as well as VS Qt tools.
after I created a new Qt empty application,
I get the error!

== Qt Visual Studio Tools version 2.4.3

Initialized in: 3164.53 msecs
   Main (UI) thread: 116.9 msecs

QtApplication5.vcxproj: background build FAILED!
QtApplication5.vcxproj: background build FAILED!

It'd be appreciated if u could solve my prob:)

Comment: I highly doubt anyone could solve your problem. You gave us no details other than a failure message. Are there any errors above the lines that are presented?

Comment: Sorry but nope... I just created a new project and it came up like this...

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem came from Qt version. Try to install older Qt versions then 5.12.6 and check whether it works